# How to access a reddit post using redditkit in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reddit, redditkit

I have a reddit post link here:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/dankmemes/comments/6m5k0o/teehee/

I wish to access the data of this post throught the redditkit API.

- http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/redditkit/

I have tried countless times and the docs don't make too much sense to me. Can someone help show how to do this through the ruby console? Or even an implementation of this in rails would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [#comment](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/redditkit/RedditKit/Client/Comments#comment-instance_method) method on the gem, it takes a `comment_full_name` and performs a `GET` to `api/info.json` with that parameter as an `id` (seen by viewing the source for that method). If we look at the reddit api for [api/info](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#GET_api_info) the `id` parameter is a `full name` for the object with a [link](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#fullnames) to what a `full name` is.

Following that link, a full name for a comment is

> Fullnames start with the type prefix for the object's type, followed by the thing's unique ID in base 36.

and

> type prefixes
>
> t1_    Comment

So now we know the `comment_full_name` should be `t1_#{comment's unique id}` which appears to be `6m5k0o`. Here, I'm unsure if that's already base36 or if they want you to convert that into base36 before passing it. Without seeing what all you've tried, I would say

```
client = RedditKit::Client.new 'username', 'password'
client.comment("t1_6m5k0o")
```

and if that doesn't work

```
client.comment("t1_#{'6m5k0o' base36 encoded}")
```

For questions like this, it would be nice to see some of your code and what you tried/results they gave. For all I know, you've already tried this and have a reason it didn't work for you.

I would test this out for you, but I don't have a reddit account for the gem to sign in with, this is just my guess glancing at the documentation.

Comment: Thanks so much! I got it working!!! And thanks for the feedback on how to ask questions too (this was my first question).